# Can I trigger the HDMI handshake programmatically

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi

My computer occasionally turns on with a completely green monitor. I've traced this issue to the HDMI connection; unplugging the HDMI cable and plugging it back in fixes the problem practically every time.

Is there any software equivalent to "plugging it in again" I can do? Some way to re-trigger the monitor *HDMI handshake*.

**Graphics Card:**

*NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080*

Comment: HDMI may be problematic and limited. Can't you use any other type of connector?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the cable?

Comment: @lpchip yeah, have tried that. I've also updated drivers for the graphics card and *generic PNP monitor*. Frankly I think it's the monitor that's at fault, it's old but if rather not replace it.